# Protractor tests - how to define import and consts once instead of repeating them in each test specification file?

Tags: typescript, protractor

I'm trying to prepare end to end tests using the [Page Object Model](https://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html) pattern. I write my tests in TypeScript, using Protractor.

I noticed that the first few lines of each test specification file looks very similar:

```
// repeated in almost every test spec file
import { protractor, browser, element, by, promise } from 'protractor';
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
const until = protractor.until;

// this is changing from test to test
const SomePage = require('./pages/99-SomePage');

// code with `describe` and `it`
```

Is it possible to not repeat those `imports` and `const`?

I've tried to `require` separate file that contains them, but it seems they're not included in my file. It is also not possible to include `Export` modifier to `import`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the *cucumber.conf* file, you can use the *onPrepare()* function to add those dependencies to the node global object, being accessible all around.
**I only suggest this for EC and other recurrent dependencies, not for Page Objects**. I use something like this:

```
...,
 onPrepare: function(){

    global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    global.until = protractor.until;

    var Logger = require('./Logger.js');
    global.logger = new Logger();

    global.data = require('./test.data.json');
 },
...
```

Comment: I will check it...but in your answer there's no import. Is it allowed in this file?

Comment: It's a bit tricky using typescript, but yes, you can. https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3629